# get parameter value in async method called with beginInvoke

Tags: c#, multithreading

I would like to get the value passed to the method (that is "Hello world") through the target variable, if possible. I looked and tested all its properties, but they expose the name of the parameter but not its value, as I could see. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class ThreadTest
{   
    static void Main()
    {
        IAsyncResult output;
        Func<string, int> method = Worker;        
        output = method.BeginInvoke("Hello world!", Done, method);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Done(IAsyncResult cookie) 
    {
        var target = (Func<string, int>)cookie.AsyncState;
        int result = target.EndInvoke(cookie);
        Console.WriteLine("String length is " + result);        
    }

    static int Worker(string s)
    {
        return s.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get input argument inside callback method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244205/get-input-argument-inside-callback-method)

Comment: I´m trying to retrieve the parameter value I passed to method.BeginInvoke()  from target variable, if possible (the value is "Hello world!")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IAsyncState` does not store the input arguments. So you cannot directly use this mechanism to retrieve the argument to the delegate.

But there are 2 ways for you to go about retrieving the argument.

1. Make the argument a `ref` argument
2. Pass the argument in the `@object` parameter for retrieval later

Example for Use case #1

```
delegate int Foo(ref string arg);

static void Main() {
    Foo method = Worker;
    var arg1 = "Hello world!";
    var output = method.BeginInvoke(ref arg1, Done, method);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Done(IAsyncResult cookie) {
    var target = (Foo)cookie.AsyncState;
    string arg1 = "";
    int result = target.EndInvoke(ref arg1, cookie);
    Console.WriteLine("String length is " + result);
    Console.WriteLine("Passed argument was " + arg1);
}

static int Worker(ref string s) {
    return s.Length;
}
```

Notice how I am using `Foo` which has a `ref string` argument instead of `Func`

Example for case #2:

```
static void Main() {
    Func<string, int> method = Worker;
    var arg1 = "Hello world!";
    var output = method.BeginInvoke(arg1, Done, Tuple.Create(method, arg1));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Done(IAsyncResult cookie) {
    var target = (Tuple<Func<string, int>, string>)cookie.AsyncState;
    int result = target.Item1.EndInvoke(cookie);
    Console.WriteLine("String length is " + result);
    Console.WriteLine("Passed argument was " + target.Item2);
}

static int Worker(string s) {
    return s.Length;
}
```

Notice how I am passing in a `Tuple` to hold the original delegate and the argument to the delegate.